# Nodejs and Express - Nested routers not hitting controller function

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

A user has a profile object and a profile has an array of interests

```
let UserSchema = new Schema({

        email: {
            value: {
                type: String,
                lowercase: true,
                //unique: true,

            },
            token: String,
            verified: Boolean,
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
        },

        phone: {
            countryCode: {
                type: String,
                //required:true,
                unique: true,
            },
            number: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            code: String,
            verified: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            },
        },

        jwt: String,

        profile: {
            username: String,
            firstname: String,
            lastname: String,
            dob: String,
            level: Number,
            location: String,
            image: String,
            introduction: String,

            languages: {
                teach: [{
                    code: String,
                    name: String,
                    native: String,
                    level: Number,
                }],
                learn: [{
                    code: String,
                    name: String,
                    native: String,
                    level: Number,
                }],
            },
            interests: [],
            countries: [],
        },
    },
    {
        timestamps: {createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at'}
    });
```

I have a scenario where i just want to add interests to a users profile. The request would be something like this to show all the users interest.

GET: /users/:id/profile/interest

user.router.js

```
'use strict';

let express    = require('express');
let router     = express.Router();
let controller = require('../controllers/user.controller');
controller     = new controller();

router.get('/', controller.index);
router.get('/:id', controller.show);
router.post('/', controller.store);
router.put('/:id', controller.update);
router.delete('/:id', controller.destroy);

router.use('/:id/profile', require('./profile.route'));

module.exports = router;
```

profile.router.js

```
let express    = require('express');
let router     = express.Router({mergeParams: true});
let controller = require('../controllers/profile.controller');
controller     = new controller();

router.get('/', controller.index);
router.get('/:id', controller.show);
router.post('/', controller.store);
router.put('/:id', controller.update);
router.delete('/:id', controller.destroy);

router.use('/interest', require('./interest.route'));

module.exports = router;
```

interest.router.js

```
'use strict';

let express    = require('express');
let router     = express.Router({mergeParams: true});
let controller = require('../controllers/interest.controller');
controller     = new controller();

router.post('/', controller.store);
router.get('/', controller.show);

module.exports = router;
```

interest.controller.js

```
show(req, res) {
    let id = req.params.id;
    console.log(id);

    User.findOne({'_id': id}, function (err, user) {

        if (err) return res.json(err);

        return res.json(user);

    });
}
```

When i call this GET: /users/:id/profile/interest request, it should hit the show function in the interest controller. However, it is not doing so. Postman gives me an error of.

```
{
    "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"interest\" at path \"_id\" for model \"User\"",
    "name": "CastError",
    "stringValue": "\"interest\"",
    "kind": "ObjectId",
    "value": "interest",
    "path": "_id"
}
```

How do i solve this?

P.S If you can think of a more efficient way to do this process please this let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your route is being matched earlier than you want, try moving your `router.use` line up a bit in your `profile.router.js` code:

```
let express    = require('express');
let router     = express.Router({mergeParams: true});
let controller = require('../controllers/profile.controller');
controller     = new controller();

router.use('/interest', require('./interest.route')); 

router.get('/', controller.index);
router.get('/:id', controller.show); /* the /interest route was being matched here */
router.post('/', controller.store);
router.put('/:id', controller.update);
router.delete('/:id', controller.destroy);

module.exports = router;
```

`

Comment: yes you are right, if i wanted in the old place i need to supply a profile id. So the question i have now is why does my profile object not have its own id?